# Can't read a single double value from a file (C)

Tags: c, file

I am having trouble reading in just a single data point from a file. It is supposed to be able to read two columns of data (such as x and y values), but I found out my code cannot even read a single value of double precision. Any help would be appreciated.

The file is at `D:\test.txt`
and there is a single value of `1.11111`.

> Enter the location of file (text file) of the airfoil coordinates: D:\test.txt
>   There are 1 lines
>   The amount of data in x and y is 1 points and 1 points.
>   failed to read.
>   *** Process returned 1 ***
>   Press any key to continue...

That was my input.

```
/*
    Purpose:
        Create a program that can take in a list of data points that represents an airfoil from some file.
        Then through the use of spline function, spline the data points for interpolation then go on to plotting them.
        With these data points, use the Vortex Panel Method to obtain coefficients of lift, pressure, and tangential velocity.
        Then after these are calculated, plot each with respect to the splined x data points.
*/

#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LEN 12

int countlines(FILE *fp);

int main (void)
{
    char airfoil[500];
    double *x_data = NULL; 
    double *y_data = NULL;
    FILE *pfile = NULL;
    int line_count = 0;
    double test = 0.0;


    printf("Enter the location of file (text file) of the airfoil coordinates: ");
    scanf("%s", airfoil);

    if(fopen_s(&pfile, airfoil, "r"))
    {
        printf("Error opening the file for reading the data. Program terminated.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    line_count = countlines(pfile);

    printf("There are %d lines\n", line_count);

    x_data = realloc(x_data, line_count*(sizeof(double)));
    y_data = realloc(y_data, line_count*(sizeof(double)));

    if((!x_data) || (!y_data))
    {
        printf("Memory allocation has failed. Exiting...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("The amount of data in x and y is %zu points and %zu points.\n", (sizeof(x_data)/sizeof(double)), (sizeof(y_data)/sizeof(double)));

     if(EOF == fscanf_s(pfile, "%lf", &test))
     {
            printf("failed to read.\n");
            exit(1);
    } 
    //for(int i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
    //{
        //fscanf(pfile, " %lf", &x_data[i]);
    //}

    printf("The x-data are %lf!\n", test);
    //for(int i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
    //{
        //printf("%.2lf", x_data[i]);
        //printf("\n");
    //}

    return 0;
}

int countlines(FILE *fp)
{   
    int lines = 0;
    char str[LEN];
    while(!feof(fp))
    {  
        if (fgets(str, LEN, fp) != NULL);
            {
                lines++;
            }
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: You should add the following information into the question itself: what did you input, and what was the output of the program.

Comment: 1) `while(!feof(fp))` feof() is always wrong 2) `if (fgets(str, LEN, fp) != NULL);` you don't want the `;` here 3) `for (lines=0;fgets(str, LEN, fp); lines++) {;}` is shorter and also correct.

Answer (score 0):

`countlines` just brought the file pointer to the end of file. Before you can read anything, you must first rewind the file to the beginning:

```
fseek(pfile,0,SEEK_SET);
```

You can do ths in `countlines()`.

See also the comments, that spot some more errors.

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot that I needed to move the file position to the start!